# Expecting partial arrays using PHPUnit mock objects

Tags: php, phpunit

What is the best way to test for multiple array keys in a PHPUnit mock `with()` clause?

For example, to test whether a method calls 2nd argument is an array containing a `'foo'` key:

```
$this->stubDispatcher->expects($this->once())
        ->method('send')
        ->with('className', $this->arrayHasKey('foo'));
```

What I'd like to do is something like `$this->arrayHasKey('foo', 'bar')` while not actually matching the exact contents of the array.

Comment: http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/extending-phpunit.html Have you read this chapter of the manual? You can extend PHPUunit to create your own constrains.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen that. I was just hoping to not have to roll my own.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass assertions directly to `->with()` but they are named differently.

For the list take a look at the source: `https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/3.5/PHPUnit/Framework/Assert.php#L2097` and following. Everything that doesn't start with "assert" and returns a `new PHPUnit_Framework_*`.

While i assume @David's answer works I think this approach, using `logicalAnd()` is a little cleaner / easier to read.

```
$mock->expects($this->once())->method("myMethod")->with(
    $this->logicalAnd(
        $this->arrayHasKey("foo"),
        $this->arrayHasKey("bar")
    )
);
```

## Working example

```
<?php


class MyTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    public function testWorks() {
        $mock = $this->getMock("stdClass", array("myMethod"));
        $mock->expects($this->once())->method("myMethod")->with(
            $this->logicalAnd(
                $this->arrayHasKey("foo"),
                $this->arrayHasKey("bar")
            )
        );
        $array = array("foo" => 1, "bar" => 2);
        $mock->myMethod($array);
    }

    public function testFails() {
        $mock = $this->getMock("stdClass", array("myMethod"));
        $mock->expects($this->once())->method("myMethod")->with(
            $this->logicalAnd(
                $this->arrayHasKey("foo"),
                $this->arrayHasKey("bar")
            )
        );
        $array = array("foo" => 1);
        $mock->myMethod($array);
    }

}
```

## Output

```
phpunit assertArrayKey.php 
PHPUnit 3.5.13 by Sebastian Bergmann.

.F

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 6.50Mb

There was 1 failure:

1) MyTest::testFails
Expectation failed for method name is equal to <string:myMethod> when invoked 1 time(s)
Parameter 0 for invocation stdClass::myMethod(array( <string:foo> => <integer:1> )) does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that an array has the key <string:bar>.

/home/edo/test/assertArrayKey.php:27
```

Comment: How would it look like if I have a nested array, like $array = ['foo' => ['lorem' => 'ipsum]] ?

Answer (score 5):

You can use a callback to make multiple assertions.

```
$this->stubDispatcher->expects($this->once())
     ->method('send')
     ->will($this->returnCallback(function($class, $array) {
             self::assertEquals('className', $class);
             self::assertArrayHasKey('foo', $array);
             self::assertArrayHasKey('bar', $array);
     }));
```

**Edit:** And if you want to make basic assertions about some parameters and more complicated assertions about the others, you can add `with()`.

```
$this->stubDispatcher->expects($this->once())
     ->method('send')
     ->with('className', $this->anything())
     ->will($this->returnCallback(function($class, $array) {
             self::assertArrayHasKey('foo', $array);
             self::assertArrayHasKey('bar', $array);
     }));
```

To be super clear, you should never pass `$this->returnCallback()` to `with()`. Same for `returnValue()` and `throwException()`. These are all directives that tell the mock what to do when the method is called. `with()` is for telling the mock what parameters it should accept.

Comment: Thanks, this is handy. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with with().

Comment: Are you sure? I haven't combined them before, but I would expect them to work together. However, the above was intended to replace the existing `with()` you had.

Comment: I know, weird right? I'm on phpunit 3.5.13, and I get an expectation error like the following:  `Failed asserting that <string:className> is equal to PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_Stub_ReturnCallback Object (etc)`

Comment: Ah, now I see the problem. Read my code again. I am using `will()` to set the `ReturnCallback`--not `with()`.

Comment: Right, I had noticed that. Sorry if it was not clear from the comment.

Comment: Does my edit make this more clear? Are you using `with()` and `will()` together in the same expectation (should work as above), or are you using `with(returnCallback(...))`? The latter will not work.

Comment: Yes, I now know that the latter won't work. I initially thought based on your response that `with()` would work with `returnCallback()`, then realized that I was dumb and it couldn't possibly work that way. Unless I'm missing something, PHPUnit has no way to pass a callback to match arguments given via `with()`. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: @Kris - Glad to help. If I did, please consider accepting my answer. :)